# Doubt about non functional requirements

Tags: requirements

I have some doubts about non functional requirements in a web app. Are quality attributes non functional requirements? Also, these are all examples of non functional requirements?

- The system should have a score >= 80 in PageSpeed
- All network transactions should be encrypted
- The users need to login to the system to access the administrator panel
- 90% of new users should be able to perform the main tasks (task 1 and task 2) of the system without any error the first time they perform the task
- The system should be compatible with the main browsers

?

Comment: Hi Carrick, on this site, askers are expected to do some research on their own before they ask. So what exactly are your own doubts/thoughts about the examples you gave? Please clarify, or don't be astonished if the community here will add more downvotes and close your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general rule that I follow for non-functional requirements are those things ending it "ilities", like: scalability, availability, reliability, etc... and then performance and security related requirements as well.

So, in your examples, here's how I would tag them:

- PageSpeed (Performance: Nonfunctional)
- Encrypted transactions (Security: Nonfunctional)
- Admin panel (Security: Nonfunctional)
- 90% of new users understand the system immediately (Usability: Nonfunctional)
- Browser (Compatibility: Nonfunctional)